# Report results and security

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql

I want to make sure I understand something.

One of the users created a report, and it returned 1 record. When I ran her report, it also returned 1 record. When I rebuilt the report from scratch (I'm a system Admin) I got 130 records, and when I did a SOQL search it returned 130 records.

This makes me think that there is something going on in terms of permissions associated with this report.

Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AHHH- I got it, and it's a frustrating one!!

The report was on a m-d-r, and it was built to return records with 1 child (inner join). The user's report had fields from the master and the detail.

My report only had fields from the master, and therefore it returned all the records. when i added fields from the detail, it went back down to 1.

Fix: change the report type from an inner join to a left join

Answer (score 0):

1. Does the report say something like "My Opportunities" and what you have built says "All Opportunities".
2. Some reports remember their creator's position in Role/Territory hierarchy (especially the ones associated to Accounts and Opportunities I think). You can read about it a bit more [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005351). So if the user was somewhere down the food chain but you're on the top that might explain it. I don't think it can be changed anywhere in the report editor - just run it, examine the hierarchy listed on the top of the report, change hierarchy to the top Role and save.

   - Are any of the Opportunities owned by users without Role (`WHERE Owner.UserRoleId = null`)? If they've completely fallen outside the hierarchy (or if you have 2 branches) this might be the reason. *It's stupid but sometimes IT is told to move deactivated users out of the Roles tree without transferring records to their managers/peers.*
   - Same for Territories if they're enabled in the org.
3. If none of these works - have you by any chance accessed the report by clicking a chart in dashboard?
4. Are you 100% all "quick access" filters on the report are set in same way in both the reports and the SOQL:

   - Date filter (set to all time?)
   - Status (all? closed? closed won?)
   - Probability (all?)
   - Opportunity teams...
   - etc.

---

Anything special about your sharing? Org-Wide Defaults? Sharing rules? Is it really opportunities or some custom object (maybe even one that's a detail in M-D?)...

Comment: 1. it says all opps. 2, she's  high up on the food chain, and 3. I  accessed the report through the reports tab... I am thinking there's something going on with roles too...

Comment: Yup, upvoted :) You got me at "When I rebuilt the report from scratch" I trusted you've used same report type. Nice catch and I'll remember it if I'll ever have similar problems again (as you can see, I've already encountered a fair share of WTF moments on inconsistent report results :))

Comment: I did use the same report type! But in the report, i only included fields from the master. That doesn't force an inner join. when you include fields from the detail, you get the inner join... That'll make you go grey!

Comment: Heh, even better then, I had no idea this works like that... Kinda makes sense though, you can still use the cross filter "parents without children"...

Comment: makes so much sense, that it took forever to figure it out? :)

Comment: I honestly never spent time thinking about it :) And my first reaction would be that custom rep. type should respect it's join type all the time, even if not all fields are shown... That's "natural" if you'd be writing the SELECT statement in normal SQL language yourself, right?

Comment: yea, i'd think so.  In sql, i'd think that you'd still get 1 record, not the full 130.